# Declaring variables creating a trigger in MySql error

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers, declaration

I'm having a little problem creating a trigger, because I have to declare a few variables, and then do some update operation with using them. Anyway, I'm gonna paste the code, and the error that it throws, and hopefully someone will tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trg_league_info
    AFTER UPDATE ON matchs
    BEGIN
       DECLARE HomeTotalMatchCount ,HomeWinMatchCount ,HomeDrawMatchCount ,HomeLossMatchCount ,HomeLeagueScore ,HomeAgainstGoal ,HomeForGoal ,HomeAverage INT DEFAULT 0;

       DECLARE AwayTotalMatchCount ,AwayWinMatchCount ,AwayDrawMatchCount ,AwayLossMatchCount ,AwayLeagueScore ,AwayAgainstGoal ,AwayForGoal ,AwayAverage INT DEFAULT 0;

       DECLARE HomeTeamID ,AwayTeamID ,HomeScore ,AwayScore ,SeasonID ,Status INT DEFAULT 0;

       SELECT @HomeTeamID=HomeID, @AwayTeamID=AwayID , @HomeScore=HomeScore , @AwayScore=AwayScore ,@SeasonID=SeasonID , @Status=Status FROM inserted;

       IF (@Status == 2) THEN
          SELECT @HomeTotalMatchCount=LeagueTotalMatchCount , @HomeWinMatchCount=LeagueWinCount , @HomeDrawMatchCount=LeagueDrawCount , @HomeLossMatchCount=LeagueLossCount  , @HomeAgainstGoal=LeagueAgaintsGoalCount , @HomeForGoal=LeagueForGoalCount , @HomeAverage=    LeagueAvarage , @HomeLeagueScore = LeagueScore FROM team_info WHERE TeamID == @HomeTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
          SELECT @AwayTotalMatchCount=LeagueTotalMatchCount , @AwayWinMatchCount=LeagueWinCount , @AwayDrawMatchCount=LeagueDrawCount , @AwayLossMatchCount=LeagueLossCount  , @AwayAgainstGoal=LeagueAgaintsGoalCount , @AwayForGoal=LeagueForGoalCount , @AwayAverage=    LeagueAvarage , @AwayLeagueScore = LeagueScore FROM team_info WHERE TeamID == @AwayTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
        
          IF (@HomeScore>@AwayScore) THEN
             uPDATE team_info SET LeagueTotalMatchCount=@HomeTotalMatchCount+1 ,LeagueWinCount=@HomeWinMatchCount+1, LeagueAgaintsGoalCount=@HomeAgainstGoal+@AwayScore , LeagueForGoalCount=@HomeForGoal+@HomeScore, LeagueScore=@HomeLeagueScore+3 WHERE TeamID == @HomeTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
             uPDATE team_info SET LeagueTotalMatchCount=@AwayTotalMatchCount+1 ,LeagueLossCount=@AwayLossMatchCount+1, LeagueAgaintsGoalCount=@AwayAgainstGoal+@HomeScore , LeagueForGoalCount=@AwayForGoal+@AwayScore, LeagueScore=@AwayLeagueScore+1 WHERE TeamID == @AwayTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
          ELSEIF (@HomeScore==@AwayScore) THEN
             uPDATE team_info SET LeagueTotalMatchCount=@HomeTotalMatchCount+1 ,LeagueDrawCount=@HomeDrawMatchCount+1, LeagueAgaintsGoalCount=@HomeAgainstGoal+@AwayScore , LeagueForGoalCount=@HomeForGoal+@HomeScore, LeagueScore=@HomeLeagueScore+2 WHERE TeamID == @HomeTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
             uPDATE team_info SET LeagueTotalMatchCount=@AwayTotalMatchCount+1 ,LeagueDrawCount=@AwayDrawMatchCount+1, LeagueAgaintsGoalCount=@AwayAgainstGoal+@HomeScore , LeagueForGoalCount=@AwayForGoal+@AwayScore, LeagueScore=@AwayLeagueScore+2 WHERE TeamID == @AwayTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
          ELSE
             uPDATE team_info SET LeagueTotalMatchCount=@HomeTotalMatchCount+1 ,LeagueLossCount=@HomeLossMatchCount+1, LeagueAgaintsGoalCount=@HomeAgainstGoal+@AwayScore , LeagueForGoalCount=@HomeForGoal+@HomeScore, LeagueScore=@HomeLeagueScore+1 WHERE TeamID == @HomeTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
             uPDATE team_info SET LeagueTotalMatchCount=@AwayTotalMatchCount+1 ,LeagueWinCount=@AwayWinMatchCount+1, LeagueAgaintsGoalCount=@AwayAgainstGoal+@HomeScore , LeagueForGoalCount=@AwayForGoal+@AwayScore, LeagueScore=@AwayLeagueScore+3 WHERE TeamID == @AwayTeamID AND SeasonID==@SeasonID;
          END IF;    
       END IF;  
    END
```

It throws the following error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN DECLARE HomeTotalMatchCount ,HomeWinMatchCount ,HomeDrawMatchCount ,H' at line 3

Last time i wrote a trigger I did it in MSSQL Server and the syntax is a little different. Maybe I'm just going to need to create a procedure and call it instead. SO if anyone can help, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax for trigger. Check [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html), you must add `FOR EACH ROW` construction. Like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_league_info
AFTER UPDATE ON matchs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Also, note that you are declaring variables, but not using them. `HomeTotalMatchCount` and `@HomeTotalMatchCount` are different variables in MySQL. Your `HomeTotalMatchCount` variable is local for this trigger and can be accessed only inside it. But variables which are prefixed with `@` are user variables, they are stored in session and can be accessed everywhere inside current connection. They will persist after your trigger is executed. You must either remove declarations and use user variables or remove `@` from variable names and use local declared variables.